# Even though I am using readlines(), these functions are only allowing me to read the first non-empty line but not the lines afterwards?

Tags: python, function, class, for-loop

I dont really understand what the problem is. If the first non-empty line contains the license number I input then it prints out what I want, but as soon as I write the license number in a line afterwards, it wont print out anything. Maybe I am using readlines incorrectly?

```
def openfile(which_file): #FIXA DENNA!

    with open(which_file, "r") as file: #FELHANTERING OM FILEN INTE FINNS
         file_rows=file.readlines()
         passengers=[]
         for lines in file_rows:
             if lines !="\n":
                objekt=carclass.data_manager(lines.split()[0], lines.split()[1], lines.split()[2], lines.split()[9], lines.split()[13])
                passengers.append(objekt)
         return passengers



def history(passengers):

    which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")
    for p in passengers:
        if which_car==p.give_license_number():
           print(p.give_license_number(),p.give_size(),p.give_owner(),p.give_entry_time(), "-" ,p.give_exit_time())
           break
        else:
            print("Please write the license number of an existing car")
            return history(passengers)
class Size:

def __init__(self, small: int, medium: int, big: int):
    self.small= small
    self.medium= medium
    self.big= big

class data_manager:

def __init__(self, license_number, size, owner, entry_time, exit_time):
    self.license_number=license_number
    self.size=size
    self.owner=owner
    self.entry_time=entry_time
    self.exit_time=exit_time

def give_license_number(self):
    return self.license_number

def give_size(self):
    return self.size

def give_owner(self):
    return self.owner

def give_entry_time(self):
    return self.entry_time

def give_exit_time(self):
    return self.exit_time
```

Textfile:

PUT465 big Noel you entered the parking lot at 4:30 and left at 7:30

RCF585 big Joseph -you entered the parking lot at 4:30 and left at 6:45

If I Input PUT465, it prints out the line that contains it, but it dosent do that when I input RCF585

Comment: You can ignore the comments btw

Comment: Have you printed the output of openfile to make sure it is giving the full file? Have you checked carclass?

Comment: Yes if I print out file_rows I get all the lines. I will post carclass here

Comment: Edited now. Please feel free to check it out

Comment: What if you print each passenger, without checking for equality?
```for p in passengers: print(p.give_license_number())```

Comment: I get an error that says that passengers is not defined

Comment: Are you still running openfile first?

Comment: Your for statement is returning to the function after the if statement. You cannot go back to the function. Instead you need to check the next value of p.

Comment: What should I write in this kind of situation?

Comment: See my updated answer for change to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `history(passengers)`, you are going through a loop.

The value of p first time is `PUT465`. So it will match the `which_car`. When you give a value of `RCF585`, the condition goes into else statement. You are calling the `history(passengers)` function again. It goes through the for loop again and starts all over. Instead, set a flag and if none of the values are in passengers, then route the process back to `history(passengers)`

```
def history(passengers):

    which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")
    for p in passengers:
        if which_car==p.give_license_number():
           print(p.give_license_number(),p.give_size(),p.give_owner(),p.give_entry_time(), "-" ,p.give_exit_time())
           break
        else:
            print("Please write the license number of an existing car")
        return history(passengers) #this line is making you go back to the function without checking for next value of passengers
```

Change your code as follows:

```
def history(passengers):

    which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")
    for p in passengers:
        if which_car==p.give_license_number():
           print(p.give_license_number(),p.give_size(),p.give_owner(),p.give_entry_time(), "-" ,p.give_exit_time())
           return #instead of break

    print("Please write the license number of an existing car")
    return history(passengers) #this line will execute only if for loop did not find a value of which_car
```

Note that `return history(passengers)` will go into infinite loop unless you give a valid license plate number.